# MacBook Pro Early 2015 freezes and crashes when viewing a presentation at PowerPoint 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ms-office, crash, performance

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.6

I believe this happened for 3 times already. When I view a presentation (Slide Show Mode) at PowerPoint 2016 for Mac, there are times when it lags and freezes; I would be unable to move to the next slide or see my cursor. Consequently, the Mac restarted on its own and told me my it "restarted because of a problem."

I got this report afterwards:

```
Mon Aug 21 18:10:51 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8013dcedd3): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9623b208, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000016f7c000, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x00000000ffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff802065bc30, RBP: 0xffffff802065bca0, RSI: 0xffffff80f8995100, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x00000000ffffffff, R9:  0x0000000000000002, R10: 0xffffff8028008000, R11: 0x0000133b802ad11c
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000100, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000005
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f9623b208, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff802065b8c0 : 0xffffff8013cdab52 
0xffffff802065b940 : 0xffffff8013dcedd3 
0xffffff802065bb20 : 0xffffff8013decca3 
0xffffff802065bb40 : 0xffffff7f9623b208 
0xffffff802065bca0 : 0xffffff7f9611b6ba 
0xffffff802065bcc0 : 0xffffff7f9611b639 
0xffffff802065bcf0 : 0xffffff7f96129317 
0xffffff802065bd40 : 0xffffff7f9612939c 
0xffffff802065bd80 : 0xffffff7f962257c2 
0xffffff802065bdb0 : 0xffffff7f9622a2f6 
0xffffff802065bdf0 : 0xffffff7f9622ad37 
0xffffff802065be40 : 0xffffff7f961b993d 
0xffffff802065be80 : 0xffffff7f961999f5 
0xffffff802065bea0 : 0xffffff80142ba1a3 
0xffffff802065bf00 : 0xffffff8013d0f2da 
0xffffff802065bfb0 : 0xffffff8013dc9507 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[569DA297-BC38-35C0-B909-6E8686BE0928]@0xffffff7f96111000->0xffffff7f9617cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[CD762868-D3F5-3463-A60E-E3B41C9CC0D1]@0xffffff7f9452c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f94fd9000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer(10.1.4)[F8289D9F-6EFA-36E6-B86B-8758C6026494]@0xffffff7f96192000->0xffffff7f961e7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[CD762868-D3F5-3463-A60E-E3B41C9CC0D1]@0xffffff7f9452c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f94bed000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[569DA297-BC38-35C0-B909-6E8686BE0928]@0xffffff7f96111000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[C89107EE-2DF2-3BC3-9F6D-3133D43ED7EF]@0xffffff7f94f2b000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.12.9)[21580824-E82E-371E-8FEE-B213B71B5C58]@0xffffff7f9618b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f94fd9000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics(10.1.4)[6E4B3931-9881-3715-AB7F-305802F44B9A]@0xffffff7f96207000->0xffffff7f96294fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(108.2.4)[A522B81B-A590-3EBB-A10D-4BFE642C7BEC]@0xffffff7f94ea2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[CD762868-D3F5-3463-A60E-E3B41C9CC0D1]@0xffffff7f9452c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f94fd9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[569DA297-BC38-35C0-B909-6E8686BE0928]@0xffffff7f96111000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15G1611

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Sun Jun  4 21:43:07 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3248.70.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B370DB23-7244-3441-B95D-384442442565
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013b00000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21146274453702
last loaded kext at 16996291451682: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f967fa000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 17394086554813: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  1.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f967f3000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.12.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.1.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.46.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 86
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    43
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  43
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B24, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

This doesn't happen every time. In fact, there are instances when PowerPoint is fast and snappy. This is the only problem I've had with my Mac since switching from Windows last year.

Could anyone tell me what happened and what I could do to avoid this?

Comment: A couple of quick questions: Is this only happening with one particular PowerPoint presentation, or is it something you've noticed can happen with *any* PowerPoint presentation? If it happens with multiple presentations, is there one in particular that almost always causes a freeze/crash? Oh, and what exact version of PowerPoint?

Comment: I can happen with any PowerPoint presentation. I didn't notice a particular presentation that always causes a crash but I noticed that this often happens with presentations that have animations. I'm using PowerPoint 2016 for Mac Version 15.28 (161115).

Comment: Have you tried opening one of the PP presentations containing animations in Keynote to see if it also crashes?  At first, the slides may look different but just for testing it may help to troubleshoot the offending slides.  Keynote is free from the App Store if you need to download it and it opens PP files.